# Grails spring security core allow authentication from url

Tags: grails, spring-security

Hi I'm using grails Spring security core to authenticate my application.

The problem is that i have some controller methods that should be accessed from an ios mobile application, how do I send the security credentials from the mobile app, to keep it authorised ?

and should I send them with every request or get a token and send back?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest

Comment: Igor,  make your comment an answer so we can upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For APIs it's better to use a stateless token based authentication

Take a look at http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest - this plugin adds token-based auth to Spring Security Core, that's what you need